# React Formik: How to set default value in formik when click the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a form that uses the `formik` react library. When clicking the checkbox I want to fill some data inside an input field in that. I don't know how to do that in a Formik way.

Anyone please help me to solve this issue?

**Code I tried :**

```
<Formik initialValues={{ email: ''}}>
{({errors, touched, setFieldValue, handleSubmit, handleBlur, handleChange, isSubmitting}) => {
    return (<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {console.log('touched',touched, errors)}
        <div className="upload-container">
            OFFICIAL EMAIL
            <input onBlur={handleBlur} onChange={handleChange} id="email_id" name="email" type="email"/>
            <div className="email-error__message__div">
                {errors.email && touched.email ? errors.email : ''}
            </div>
            <div className="official-MailID__container">
                <input 
                    id="checkOffiMailId"
                    name="checkofficialmailId"
                    type="checkbox" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="button__container">
            <button className="verify-me" type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>VERIFY ME</button>
            <button className="doit-later" onClick={doItLater}>I'LL DO THIS LATER</button>
        </div>
    </Form>
)}}
</Formik>
```

I updated the question. What I want is when I clicked the `checkOffiMailId` I want to fill some data in `email_id`.

[Formik Library](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik)

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: From your link: `<Formik initialValues={{ name: 'jared' }}`. This line? If this is not what its name implies, the correct way should be in those docs you link somewhere.

Comment: @ChrisB. I updated the code.